# Install protocols in Windows 10 native VPN

Tags: windows-10, cisco-vpn

Is there any way to install a particular Cisco VPN protocol (eg. DTLS) in Windows 10's native VPN client (as shown in the screenshot)? I found apps for other protocols (Eg. Pulse Connect) in the Microsoft Store which integrate into the Windows VPN interface, but none for Cisco. The AnyConnect software itself works fine on my computer but I'd like to find a way to integrate it into Windows 10, even if it's super hacky.

In the worst case, how could I go about compiling OpenConnect for UWP? (I couldn't find any documentation online)

Exported stats from client: https://pastebin.com/brcnpAjr

[image]

Comment: Well, we wouldn't really compile anything for Universal Windows Platform, if that's what you mean. I suggest you describe what you are actually trying to accomplish, and only then explain the things you have tried that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I tried to improve my question.

Comment: AnyConnect isn't a protocol. It's a VPN client software package that supports a number of VPN related protocols.

Comment: Updated to specify the protocol and exported stats from cisco client.

Comment: As you can see from your stats, the protocol is DTLS. AnyConnect is not a protocol.

Comment: Okay thanks, you were right. Is there anything else I can do to improve the question?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is like a year late, but if anyone else looks for the answer, you can install the AnyConnect UWP from the Microsoft Store, and then you can select the Cisco AnyConnect provider within the Windows settings.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/anyconnect/9wzdncrdj8lh

Comment: It's real! great! solution! Thank you Enrigue. It should be answer!